# Web scraping: match same items having different names on different sources

Tags: web-scraping, match

I am scraping different betting sites to get best odds on the same events. Let's say I have these results regarding the same game on two different sites:

```
{
   "1": 1.27,
   "2": 10,
   "game": "Juventus - Spal 2013",
   "X": 5.45
 }
```

and

```
{
    "1": 1.28,
    "2": 11,
    "game": "Juventus - Spal",
    "X": 5.5
}
```

What is the best way I can "tell" my system that "Spal" and "Spal 2013" are the same team? (this is just an example, it can happen for a lot of events, teams and players).

Comment: The scope of a solution to this is actually quite broad imo.  What do you think you could do to achieve this?

Comment: Using a sort of "matching matrix" to find the best match between results obtained by different bookmakers. But it seems very heavy to code and execute

Comment: Do the two dictionaries in both sites always have the same keys (1,2,game and X, in your example)? And the values of "game" have the two teams in the same order (as opposed to "Spal - Juventus")?

Comment: @JackFleeting yes, keys are the same (I build JSON files after scraping) and team order is the same

Comment: OK, then, can you post a few more examples of these? It may help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I chose to use [`string-similarity`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity) package, that has the method `findBestMatch(item, targetStrings)`